# What is the name of this pattern?

Tags: pattern-drafting, weaving

What is the name of this pattern and/or how do I make it?

[image]

I assume it is plain weaving with a loom, but I am not sure.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The bracelet is done using [plain weave](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plain_weave) (also called tabby weave, linen weave or taffeta weave), which goes over one thread and under the next one alternatingly.

The patches of color initially looked like [basket weave](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basketweave_(weaving)) to me, but looking closely you see that they are simply embroidered with a different color over the plain weave ground.

To recreate something like this you'll need a simple loom, which can be bought or crafted from things like cardboard ([like this example by The Weaving Loom](https://www.theweavingloom.com/how-to-make-a-cardboard-loom/)) or a wooden frame ([like this example by Simply Handmade Studios](https://www.simplyhandmadestudios.com/blog/the-loom-how-to-make-a-weaving-loom)